# SETеры / GETеры структуры СИ как в классах С++

Tags: c, stm32

Хочу в ***СИ*** реализовать **SET**еры / **GET**еры структуры как в классах ***С++***. 
Создаю в структуре указатель на функцию и при создании экземпляра структуры передаю адрес функции.

Описываю функцию и для того чтобы вывести значение из структуры, приходится передавать адрес структуры.

**obj**.Get(&**obj**);   <-- **это как-то глупо**.

Может есть какой-то способ узнать адрес из какой структуры запущенна функция, чтобы не передавать её как аргумент?

Или посоветуйте ещё более изящный способ реализации **set**/**get** методов в си.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct object {

    void (*Get)\
    (struct object *this);// ссылка на функцию
    int number;    // Просто переменная

}ClassType;

void GetStruct(struct object *this){
    printf("%d", this->number);
}



int main(void){


    ClassType obj = {
        .number = 66,
        .Get = &GetStruct
    };


    obj.Get(&obj);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А зачем вам вообще указатели на функции в структуре? Зря расходуете место ради "красивого" синтаксиса вызова с точкой? Можно просто использовать обычные функции, что-нибудь вроде `ClassType_GetNumber(&obj);`.

Comment: Да, для чистоты кода.
Так визуально понятно, что я обращаюсь к конкретному объекту, к его методу и вложенным переменным. Всё описание, можно спрятать в библиотеки.

Comment: Вопрос из разряда "как забить гвоздь чайником". Суть голого С - не смешивать в кучу данные и методы их обработки. Не проще ли пользовать плюсы, если вам так нужны классы, в таком случае??? Вроде как законом не запрещено...

Comment: Есть такие штуки как стандарты и заказчик =) Пишу программы для контроллеров, под определённый компилятор, там чистое СИ. Под плюсы тоже пишу в QT, под STM32 только Keil. Мне говорят как оно должно быть, а я пытаюсь реализовать.

Comment: Да уж ... Вбитое в голову ортодоксальное ООП точно до добра не доведет